# Get all subfolder names as string with grunt.js

Tags: gruntjs

Is it possible to get all subfolder names as string using grunt.js?
I would need them as an array of strings.
Is there any grunt-contrib-package for this?

Comment: Can't you use Node's fs module? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback

Comment: @FelixKling, you can formulate a more detailed answer if you want, it seems like your comment solved his problem